# Deploy Node.js RestFull API to Heroku

Tags: node.js, rest, api, heroku, deployment

I have a school assignment where i must build a node.js server (**Without Express**) that receives a POST request containing **{day: 25, month:12, year:2017}** and sends the number of days remaining to that date.

I was able to solve this using **moment** npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

The server is listening on port 3000.

The code works perfectly when i send a post request to 127.0.0.1:3000

However, i changed listen port to 80, created a new app on heroku and then deployed my code and it doesn't work anymore, heroku says application crash.

Does anyone have an idea ?

server is created like this :

```
var http = require('http');
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    ....
});
server.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku uses the process.env of nodeJS. In order to make sure your app works on heroku you should set the an variable called port that takes either port 3000 / 80 for local app and process.env.PORT for heroku deployments.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Can you run the command Heroku logs and share the output here? And btw did you provide a start script in your package.json file?